# When ACTUALLY using bitcoin to buy and sell goods, is there a way to take its current price ($22,xxx) and find an actual value to it?

Tags: speculation

Because if i sell my valued item at say, 22,000 worth of bitcoin. Tomorrow, there could be a crash which brings it down to $1000 or less and i've essentially traded my $22,000 item for worthless bubble money.

Is there any term to search or people to talk to who understand bitcoins true value?

Comment: Are you asking how to "price" the risk?  There won't be a universal way; it depends on whether you are more or less risk-averse than the market as a whole.  Note, though, that if you don't want the risk of holding the bitcoin, there is an easy solution: sell the bitcoin immediately after receiving it.